# How do I parse a string with an unordered list into a generic list of strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-lists, generic-list

I have an unordered list stored in my SQL table as a string.  I need to display it later in an Excel file but I'm having trouble formatting it correctly.

I have tried using regular expressions to and I think I'm close, but I'm missing something.

This is my sample input string

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2</li>
    <li>Line 3</li>
    <li>Line 4
        <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
            <li>Line 4-1</li>
            <li>Line 4-2
                <ul style="list-style-type:square">
                    <li>Line 4-2-1</li>
                    <li>Line 4-2-2</li>
                    <li>Line 4-2-3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Line 4-3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Line 5</li>
    <li>Line 6</li>
    <li>Line 7</li>
</ul>
```

And here is what I've done so far.

```
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add();

string inputValue; //unordered list from above

            Regex rgxLI = new Regex(@"<li>(.*?)</li>");
            Regex rgxCircle = new Regex(@"<ul style=\""list-style-type:circle\"">(.*?)</ul>");
            Regex rgxSquare = new Regex(@"<ul style=\""list-style-type:square\"">(.*?)</ul>");

            MatchCollection mcLI = rgxLI.Matches(inputValue);
            for (var i = 0; i < mcLI.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                //string instructionLine = mc[i].Value;
                if (mcLI[i].Value.Contains("<ul style=\"list-style-type:circle\">"))
                {
                    MatchCollection mcCircle = rgxCircle.Matches(mcLI[i].Value);
                    for (var j = 0; j < mcCircle.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (mcLI[j].Value.Contains("<ul style=\"list-style-type:square\">"))
                        {
                            MatchCollection mcSquare= rgxSquare.Matches(mcLI[j].Value);
                            dr[0] = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#9642;" + mcSquare[j].ToString().Replace("<li>", "").Replace("</li>", ""));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dr[0] = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#8226;" + mcCircle[j].ToString().Replace("<li>", "").Replace("</li>", ""));
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    dr[0] = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(mcLI[i].Value.Replace("<li>", "").Replace("</li>", ""));

                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
```

Not sure if I'm overcomplicating things or just missing some steps.  I was able to get most of the string parsed, but I'm missing the bullet points after 4-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

list = (Regex.Split(YOURSTRING, "\r\n")).ToList<string>();
```

this should just split by each line.
It will split into an array, which is why I use .ToList().

"\r\n" is used to find the newline character with Regex